# Android 2.2 requestFocus() and spinners

Tags: android, focus, spinner

I'm having problems using s.requestFocus() when s is a spinner. Is there a special treatment to get it to work when it's a spinner ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem ? Got any logs or source code to show us ?

Comment: When I do view.requestFocus() for a spinner, it does nothing but if the view is an EditText, it works just fine.

Comment: what exactly do you wan't to do? have it in the selected state? open the spinner dialog? Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

try this code..

```
spinner.setFocusable(true);
spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you aren't literally just looking to "give focus" to the spinner.  When you give focus to an EditText, the keyboard pops up, so you may be expecting the spinner selection to "open up" on focus - but it doesn't work that way (don't ask me why).  Use s.performClick() to do this - it will act just as if the user clicked on the spinner control.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class dynamic_spinner_main extends Activity {

    private Spinner m_myDynamicSpinner;
    private EditText m_addItemText;
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m_adapterForSpinner;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_spinner);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //grab our UI elements so we can manipulate them (in the case of the Spinner)
        //    or add listeners to them (in the case of the buttons)
        m_myDynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamicSpinner);        
        m_addItemText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newSpinnerItemText);
        Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddBtn);
        Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ClearBtn);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //create an arrayAdapter an assign it to the spinner
        m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        m_adapterForSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
        m_myDynamicSpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
        m_adapterForSpinner.add("gr");        
        m_myDynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                Intent mIntent=new Intent(dynamic_spinner_main.this,sampleLocalization.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("lang", m_myDynamicSpinner.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                System.out.println("Spinner value...."+m_myDynamicSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //add listener for addButton
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                addNewSpinnerItem();
            }                   
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //add listener for addButton
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearSpinnerItems();
            }           
        });  
    }

    private void addNewSpinnerItem() {
        CharSequence textHolder = "" + m_addItemText.getText();
        m_adapterForSpinner.add(textHolder);
    }

    private void clearSpinnerItems() {
        m_adapterForSpinner.clear();
        m_adapterForSpinner.add("dummy item");
    }       
}
```

main_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:id="@+id/newSpinnerItemText" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/AddBtn" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Add To Spinner"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/ClearBtn" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Clear Spinner Items"></Button>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/dynamicSpinner" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the relation to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner isn't focusable by default ([source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=52c046d8b2f6ad46a01242a4552a5354f74c9674;hb=HEAD#l459)). So you have to make it focusable either in xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_conten"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

or in code

```
findViewById(R.id.spinner).setFocusable(true);
```